# Why maven prompt /Users/xxxx/Desktop/dev/maven-3.5.1 is not correct maven home, reverting to embedded when building dependencies?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

Why maven prompt  /Users/xxxx/Desktop/dev/maven-3.5.1 is not correct maven home, reverting to embedded when building dependencies?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It depends on what IDE you're using. Looks like it is a incorrect path for maven home. Provide more details, so others can help.